# Interpolate variables in path (bash command line)

Tags: linux, bash, bash-completion

Please, tell me, what should i do , to interpolate variable name in bash command line while I type it?

i.e. `$A = ~/tmp/`
in tmp folder I have tmp1 and tmp2 folders.

I type: `cd $A<TAB>` and nothing happes.
if i put additional / and type `cd $A/tmp1`, it will put additional space at the end `cd $A/tmp1<space>`.

I want the following behavoir:
`cd $A<TAB>` =====> `cd ~/tmp/<without additional space>`

---

Any suggestions?

Comment: solution: complete -r; shopt -s direxpand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say:

```
shopt -s direxpand
```

Now saying:

> cd $A/<kbd>TAB</kbd>

(note the `/` before <kbd>TAB</kbd>) would present directories without adding space.

From the manual:

```
direxpand
         If  set,  bash replaces directory names with the results
         of word expansion when performing  filename  completion.
         This  changes  the contents of the readline editing buf‐
         fer.  If not set, bash attempts  to  preserve  what  the
         user typed.
```

Moreover, instead of setting a variable by saying:

```
A="~/tmp"
```

or

```
A=~/tmp
```

say

```
A="${HOME}/tmp"
```

Comment: +1, but what's wrong with `A=~/tmp`? Tilde expansion occurs when an unquoted tilde is the first character in an assignment.

Comment: @chepner Nothing wrong with it.  It'd work but saying `${HOME}` appears cleaner.

Comment: Unless you want to expand someone else's home directory, then you have to use tilde expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't want any spaces on either side of your `=`.  Secondly, I have no problem with `bash` behaving the above way.  Try:

```
complete -r
```